# How do I intercept a gtk window close button click?

Tags: c, linux, gtk

On on GTK window there is a red close icon rendered in the title bar.  Normally when you click on this, the window is closed and it's resources released.

Is there a way of intercepting the normal flow to prevent the window from being destroyed so that I can show it again later? i.e. I want to hide the window not close/destroy it.

This is what I have so far.

```
void destroy_window_callback(GtkWidget* widget, WebWindow_Linux* source)
{
  printf("Don't destroy the window, just hide it.\n");
}


g_signal_connect(web_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy_window_callback), this);
```

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried anything at all. Are you handling the `"destroy"` signal?

Comment: Also, where do you want to hide it?

Comment: @iharob - I haven't tried attaching a signal because I don't know which one to catch.  Sorry I'm fairly green on GTK programming.  I just want to hide the window and not have it visible in the dock.

Comment: It's `delete-event`. Please give me a second while I post an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably what you need

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void
on_button_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *widget;
    widget = (GtkWidget *) data;
    if (widget == NULL)
        return;
    gtk_widget_show(widget);
    return;
}

gboolean
on_widget_deleted(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_widget_hide(widget);
    return TRUE;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window1;
    GtkWidget *window2;
    GtkWidget *button;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window1 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    window2 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Show again...");

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window1),
        "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window2), 
        "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(on_widget_deleted), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), 
        "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_clicked), window2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window1), button);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window1, 300, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window2, 300, 100);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window1);
    gtk_widget_show(window2);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

We basically have three widgets, two top level windows and a button. The first window has it's `"destroy"` event connected to `gtk_main_quit()` quitting the application when the window's close button is pressed. The second window has it's `"delete-event"` connected to a custom function. This is the important one. As you see it returns `TRUE` indicating that the signal was handled and thus preventing to call the default handler and hence preventing the call to `gtk_widget_destroy()`. Also in it we can hide the widget if we want.

Comment: Thanks.  That almost works for me.  Not sure why it didn't quite.  It was probably my own fault.  But at least I was capturing the window button click so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer.  In my case, what worked was instead of providing my own function I instead found and used `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete` and it worked perfectly.  i.e.     `g_signal_connect(web_window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_hide_on_delete), NULL);`

Comment: Yes that was suggested in the documentation too, but I was trying to make it clear why it worked.

Comment: Actually it does work perfectly.  The issue was another problem that made it look like it wasn't working.  All good, thanks!

Comment: Dude provide method signature for gtk_main_quit...